# Add drop down list to top action bar when split and top bar is from a layout

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I have seen a lot of similar questions to mine, but they all seem to differ in some way that makes them not so helpful.

I have a split action bar in my activity. I have customized the top action bar to display my own view since I wanted to add icons to the top and not show the launcher icon or activity title. I have added a menu with icons which appears at the bottom. Here is the code that does both these things:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic_fractions);


    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);


    View view = View.inflate(this,R.layout.action_bar_top,null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(view, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL));;
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_basic_fractions, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This code produces the effect I wanted - a split menu with some icon buttons at the top (from the layout view) and some at the bottom (from the menu)

However, I want to add a drop down list to the top action bar. I have found ways to do it if I had a menu there instead of a layout view (for example with submenus or actionLayout), but not with this mixed kind of action bar.

An alternative would be if I could add a menu instead of a layout to be in the top action bar since I am not adding anything special, just a few normal menu buttons, but I couldn't find anyway to force them to appear in the top action bar without making it a layout like this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "I have a split action bar in my activity" -- note that the split action bar is deprecated on Android 5.0+ and is not available with `Theme.Material` or `Theme.Appcompat`. "I want to add a drop down list to the top action bar" -- note that list and tab navigation in the action bar is deprecated on Android 5.0+.

Comment: My target is 3.0 and above.